# How to convert between spectra given in terms of velocity (km/s) to wavelength spectra?

Tags: galaxy, spectra, hydrogen

I have H alpha spectra of H II regions in our galaxy. In the paper, the x-axis is in units of km/s and the corresponding line width as well. From this, how can I get equivalent width of the H alpha line?

Comment: $v = c\Delta \lambda/\lambda_0$

Comment: It would be much better if you mentioned and linked to the paper and gave the actual value of the line width in km/s. The comment above works to first order, but if it's really wide the answer could turn out to be more interesting!

Comment: @uhoh- Thank You for replying. The link for the paper I am looking at is [link](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1990AJ.....99..622F). I needed to know the H alpha equivalent width of the H2 regions in units of wavelength. Am I missing something here?